# fast archiving of multiple files (no compression / encryption)

Tags: archiving

I pretty often have to pack many small files into one big file for a cloud based archiving. I'm using WinRAR, but archiving 800 GB (even without compression) this way take a few hours. Is there any way for a quick, non-encryption, non-compression archiving? I use Windows 10.

Comment: Duplicate the hard drive with a disk duplication hardware.

Comment: Tar archiver is literally intended for this type of purpose, by default no compression or encryption... Will run about as fast as you can read/write to the drive.